# How could I add dots at my graph at the end

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-chains

I would like to add dots end of my graph which shows going to infinite. However, I try several times, and it does not works. The problem is the code with **, other parts are correct. Thanks
My code is below:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->, >=stealth, auto, semithick, node distance=3cm]
\tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=white,draw=blue,thick,text=black,scale=1]

\node[state]    (0') at (0,12)  {$0\textprime$};
\node[state]    (0) at (0,9)  {$0$};



\node[state]    (1') at (3,12)  {$1\textprime$};
\node[state]    (1) at (3,9)  {$1$};



\node[state]    (2') at (6,12)  {$2\textprime$};
\node[state]    (2) at (6,9)  {$2$};



\node[state]    (3') at (9,12)  {$3\textprime$};
\node[state]    (3) at (9,9)  {$3$};


\node[state]    (4') at (12,12)  {$4\textprime$};
\node[state]    (4)  at (12,9)   {$4$};

**\node[dots]     (d) at  (15,12)  {$\dots$};
\node[dots]     (d) at  (15,9)   {$\dots$};**





\path
(0')  edge[bend left]     node{$\lambda$} (1')
      edge[bend left]     node{$\beta$} (0)

(0)   edge[bend left]     node{$\alpha$} (0')
      edge[bend left]     node{$\lambda$} (1)


(1)   edge[bend left]     node{$\mu$}     (0)
      edge[bend left]     node{$\lambda$} (2)
      edge[bend left]     node{$\alpha$}  (1')

(1')  edge[bend left]     node{$\mu$} (0')
      edge[bend left]     node{$\beta$} (1)
      edge[bend left]     node{$\lambda$} (2')

(1)   edge[bend left]     node{$\mu$}     (0)
      edge[bend left]     node{$\alpha$}  (1')
      edge[bend left]     node{$\lambda$} (2)

(2)   edge[bend left]     node{$\mu$}     (1)
      edge[bend left]     node{$\lambda$} (3)
      edge[bend left]     node{$\alpha$}  (2')

(2')  edge[bend left]     node{$\beta$}     (2)
      edge[bend left]     node{$\mu$} (1')
      edge[bend left]     node{$\lambda$}  (3')

(3')  edge[bend left]     node{$\mu$} (2')
      edge[bend left]     node{$\lambda$}  (4')
      edge[bend left]     node{$\beta$}    (3)

(3)   edge[bend left]     node{$\mu$}     (2)
      edge[bend left]     node{$\alpha$}  (3')
      edge[bend left]     node{$\lambda$} (4)
(4)   edge[bend left]     node{$\mu$}     (3)
      edge[bend left]     node{$\alpha$}  (4')

(4')  edge[bend left]     node{$\beta$}    (4)
      edge[bend left]     node{$\mu$}      (3')
;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{figure}
\clearpage
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Rather than posting code fragments it is better to give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what packages etc you are using and this makes it much harder to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Answer (score 1):

Your diagram does a lot of repetitive stuff.  Better use loops.

In the end I place the dots right of the last nodes of each row.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  >=stealth,
  semithick,
  every state/.style={draw=blue,thick}
  ]
  \foreach \i in {0,...,4}
  {
    \node[state] (n-\i) at (3*\i,0) {$\i$};
    \node[state] (p-\i) at (3*\i,3) {$\i'$};

    \draw[->] (n-\i) to[bend left] node[left]  {$\alpha$} (p-\i);
    \draw[->] (p-\i) to[bend left] node[right] {$\beta$}  (n-\i);
  }
  \foreach \x in {n,p} {
    \foreach \i[remember=\i as \last (initially 0)] in {1,...,4} {
      \draw[->] (\x-\last) to[bend left] node[above] {$\lambda$} (\x-\i);
      \draw[->] (\x-\i)    to[bend left] node[below] {$\mu$}     (\x-\last);
    }
  }
  \node[right=.1cm of n-4] {$\dots$};
  \node[right=.1cm of p-4] {$\dots$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you don't want to place the nodes by hand, you could use a matrix.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,matrix,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  >=stealth,
  semithick,
  every state/.style={draw=blue,thick}
  ]
  \matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes=state,row sep=2cm,column sep=2cm] (m) {
    0' & 1' & 2' & 3' & 4' \\
    0  & 1  & 2  & 3  & 4  \\
  };
  \foreach \c in {1,...,5} {
    \draw[->] (m-2-\c) to[bend left] node[left]  {$\alpha$} (m-1-\c);
    \draw[->] (m-1-\c) to[bend left] node[right] {$\beta$}  (m-2-\c);
  }
  \foreach \r in {1,2} {
    \foreach \c[remember=\c as \last (initially 1)] in {2,...,5} {
      \draw[->] (m-\r-\last) to[bend left] node[above] {$\lambda$} (m-\r-\c);
      \draw[->] (m-\r-\c)    to[bend left] node[below] {$\mu$}     (m-\r-\last);
    }
  }
  \node[right=.1cm of m-1-5] {$\dots$};
  \node[right=.1cm of m-2-5] {$\dots$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, for your mention. Also, what should I do if I only need the horizontal line? only 0,1,2,3,4,....... Thanks

Comment: @dorothy Well, you should remove the nodes and arrow of the upper line then.

Comment: Also, the part I did not figure is, this time I need mu1,mu2,mu3, and lambda0, lambda1,...

Comment: I trying to remove it, but it keep to telling me error, if you do not mind, could you show me your code again? Thanks

Comment: @dorothy Here is the adapted code for the [first](http://hastebin.com/agulobopev.tex) and the [second](http://hastebin.com/neretevodu.tex) solution.  As you see it is only a matter of commenting out a few lines.  You really should read the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) if you already have troubles modifying this relatively simple TikZ code.  I learned TikZ by completing the tutorial in Part I.